# Why is the mat-autocomplete not displaying the searched options?

Tags: angular, autocomplete, angular-material, angular10

This is the form that I am using:

```
<form [formGroup]="searchForm" id="searchForm">
   <mat-form-field>
      <input
      matInput
      type="text"
      name="awesome"
      id="awesome"
      [formControl] = "formCtrl"
      [matAutocomplete] = "auto"
      value="{{ awesomeText }}"
      [matAutocomplete]="auto">
      <mat-autocomplete #auto = "matAutocomplete">
         <mat-option *ngFor = "let res of result | async" [value] = "res">
         {{res}}
         </mat-option>
      </mat-autocomplete>
   </mat-form-field>
</form>
```

And this is inside `constructor()`:

```
this.formCtrl = new FormControl();
this.formCtrl.valueChanges.subscribe((newValue) => {
    this.result = this.find(newValue);
    console.log('yes');
});
```

The `yes` is printing so I know that this is working but `mat-autocomplete` does not show anything. The `result` variable is also updating as I can see it printing on console. I am not able to understand why the searched values are not being displayed.

I would appreciate any help!

**Edit**

This is the `find()` method:

```
find(val: string): string[] {
    const matchFound = [];

    for (let i = 0; i < dataJson.length; i++) {
        if (dataJson[i].text.toLowerCase().startsWith(val) || dataJson[i].text.startsWith(val)) {
            matchFound.push(dataJson[i].text);
        }
    }

    console.log('matches ' + matchFound);
    return matchFound;
}
```

Comment: What does your method `this.find` do? post your code

Comment: this.result should hold array of matched strings. What is this.result holding in the code you shared?

Comment: @Shank Updated the code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should assign Observable of string array to the `this.result`. But you are assigning normal string array. `async` pipe works with observable not with the normal array. And in the template you need below change

**From**

```
<mat-option *ngFor="let res of result | async" [value]="res">{{res}}</mat-option>
```

**To**

```
<mat-option *ngFor="let res of result | async" [value]="res.text">{{res.text}}</mat-option>
```

**Typescript changes**

```
ngOnInit() {
  this.result = this.myControl.valueChanges.pipe(
    startWith(""),
    map(value => this.find(value))
  );
}

find(val: string): {
  id: number,
  text: string
}[] {
  const matchFound: {
    id: number,
    text: string
  }[] = [];

  for (let i = 0; i < this.dataJson.length; i++) {
    if (
      this.dataJson[i].text.toLowerCase().startsWith(val) ||
      this.dataJson[i].text.startsWith(val)
    ) {
      matchFound.push(this.dataJson[i]);
    }
  }

  console.log("matches " + matchFound);
  return matchFound;
}
```

Working [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-cac998)